# How to fill the height of a `TableCell` completely?

Tags: javafx

I need to implement the TableView as shown in the left diagram, but I can only achieve the appearance shown in the right diagram.
[image]    [image]

```
freq.setCellFactory(new Callback<TableColumn<Item, String>, TableCell<Item, String>>() {
            @Override
            public TableCell<Item, String> call(TableColumn<Item, String> itemStringTableColumn) {
                return new TableCell<>(){

                    @Override
                    protected void updateItem(String item, boolean empty) {
                        super.updateItem(item, empty);
                        Rectangle rectangle = new Rectangle();
                        rectangle.setFill(Paint.valueOf("grey"));
                        rectangle.setHeight(20);
                        rectangle.setWidth(30);
                        setGraphic(new HBox(rectangle, new Label(item)){{setStyle("-fx-alignment: CENTER_LEFT;-fx-spacing: 15");}});
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void startEdit() {
                        super.startEdit();
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void cancelEdit() {
                        super.cancelEdit();
                    }
                };
            }
        });
```

Comment: What is that long thing with an arrow in it in your picture that is spanning the table rows? Is it a button?  What is it supposed to do? What is the arrow in it for?  How is the arrow supposed to work?

Comment: @jewelsea The arrow can move up and down within that elongated strip, serving as an indicator for a particular row.

Comment: Probably all you need to do is call `setStyle("-fx-background-color: silver;")` in the cell constructor (if you want the styling in all cells in the column) or the `updateItem` call if you only want the styling in some cells.  That would be if you want to color the entire cell.  If it is just a portion of the cell, you can set the background color using a linear gradient with stops.  But I didn't try it.  If it were me, I'd consider splitting the Freq column into two columns, one for the indicator strip with the arrow and the other for the actual Freq value.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In the screenshot of what you want, that gray column with the arrow on the selected row does not look to be part of the "Freq" column. So, I would implement this by adding a separate column to the table. This column would:

- Be the first column.
- Have its text set to the empty string/null (i.e., have no title/label).
- Be non-resizable, non-reordable, non-sortable, and non-editable.
- Use some sort of gray color for the background of all its non-empty cells; if there is no padding between the rows then it will look like all the cells are one node.
- Have an arrow as the graphic of each cell that is only visible when the row is selected.
- Have a set width only large enough for the arrow.
- Not contain any data.

Here is an example:

```java
package com.example;

import java.nio.charset.StandardCharsets;
import java.util.Base64;
import java.util.function.Function;
import java.util.function.Supplier;
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.beans.property.SimpleObjectProperty;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.TableCell;
import javafx.scene.control.TableColumn;
import javafx.scene.control.TableView;
import javafx.scene.layout.Region;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class Main extends Application {

    private static final String STYLESHEET =
            """
            .indicator-table-cell {
                -fx-background-color: derive(-fx-color, -8%);
            }

            .indicator-table-cell:empty {
                -fx-background-color: transparent;
            }

            .indicator-table-cell .indicator {
                -fx-background-color: black;
                -fx-shape: "M 0 -3.5 L 4 0 L 0 3.5 z";
                -fx-scale-shape: false;
                visibility: hidden;
            }

            .table-row-cell:selected .indicator-table-cell .indicator {
                visibility: visible;
            }
            """;

    private static String dataUriStylesheet() {
        // base64-encoded data URI used to avoid needing to escape the '%' in the CSS
        var bytes = STYLESHEET.getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
        return "data:text/css;charset=utf-8;base64," + Base64.getEncoder().encodeToString(bytes);
    }

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
        var table = new TableView<Data>();
        table.getItems().addAll(new Data(1, 2), new Data(2, 3), new Data(3, 4));

        // This column will be the gray-ish column where its cells will have an
        // arrow visible when the associated row is selected.
        var indicatorCol = createColumn("", d -> null, IndicatorTableCell::new);
        indicatorCol.setMaxWidth(30); // arbitrarily chosen width
        indicatorCol.setResizable(false);
        indicatorCol.setEditable(false);
        indicatorCol.setReorderable(false);
        indicatorCol.setSortable(false);

        table.getColumns().add(indicatorCol);
        table.getColumns().add(createColumn("Freq", Data::frequency, null));
        table.getColumns().add(createColumn("Time", Data::time, null));

        var scene = new Scene(table, 500, 300);
        scene.getStylesheets().add(dataUriStylesheet());

        primaryStage.setScene(scene);
        primaryStage.show();
    }

    private <T> TableColumn<Data, T> createColumn(
            String text, Function<Data, T> valueFactory, Supplier<TableCell<Data, T>> cellFactory) {
        var column = new TableColumn<Data, T>(text);
        column.setCellValueFactory(cdf -> new SimpleObjectProperty<>(valueFactory.apply(cdf.getValue())));
        if (cellFactory != null) {
            column.setCellFactory(tc -> cellFactory.get());
        }
        return column;
    }

    // Basic model class for example; used record to make example less verbose
    public record Data(int frequency, int time) {}

    // The TableCell implementation used by the "indicator column"
    public static class IndicatorTableCell<S> extends TableCell<S, Void> {

        // Shape and visibility controlled by CSS
        private final Region indicator = new Region();

        public IndicatorTableCell() {
            indicator.getStyleClass().add("indicator");
            getStyleClass().add("indicator-table-cell");
        }

        @Override
        protected void updateItem(Void item, boolean empty) {
            super.updateItem(item, empty);
            setGraphic(empty ? null : indicator);
        }
    }
}
```

And here is a screenshot of the example:

[image: screenshot of example]

<sup>**Note:** The selected row is highlighted gray because the window does not have focus (due to the way the screenshot was taken), otherwise it would be that distinctive JavaFX blue.</sup>

In order to make the example easier to run, the CSS is defined as a mutiline string and added to the scene as a data URI (this requires JavaFX 17+). For convenience, here is the CSS separately:

```css
.indicator-table-cell {
    -fx-background-color: derive(-fx-color, -8%);
}

.indicator-table-cell:empty {
    -fx-background-color: transparent;
}

.indicator-table-cell .indicator {
    -fx-background-color: black;
    -fx-shape: "M 0 -3.5 L 4 0 L 0 3.5 z";
    -fx-scale-shape: false;
    visibility: hidden;
}

.table-row-cell:selected .indicator-table-cell .indicator {
    visibility: visible;
}
```

The shape used for the "indicator" was taken from [modena.css](https://github.com/openjdk/jfx/blob/master/modules/javafx.controls/src/main/resources/com/sun/javafx/scene/control/skin/modena/modena.css) (the default user agent stylesheet for JavaFX 8+). It is the same shape defined for the "disclosure nodes" used in tree views. The `-fx-color` is a ["looked-up color"](https://openjfx.io/javadoc/21/javafx.graphics/javafx/scene/doc-files/cssref.html#typecolor) and is also defined in *modena.css*.